# Flask-Asset does not create correct url on template

Tags: flask, flask-assets

I cannot figure out why Flask-CDN is not building my templates with the Amazon CloudFront url for my static files. Here is my setup:

1) Configure cdn domain and ask Flask-Assets to use cdn:

```
class AppConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False
    FLASK_ASSETS_USE_CDN = True
    CDN_DOMAIN = "mydomain.cloudfront.net"
```

2) The Flask app with the CDN object:

```
config_object = AppConfig
app = flask.Flask(config_object.PROJECT_NAME, static_folder='web/static')
app.config.from_object(config_object)

# Bundles are configured here (many of them!) to generate the app.js file

if config_object.DEBUG is False:
    CDN(app)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

3) The template that uses the assets:

```
{% assets "js_app" %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}
```

4) Finally, the html built by the server was:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/gen/app.js?40c12882"></script>
```

I'm wondering why the html doesn't contain my CDN domain, as it should have been generated like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.cloudfront.net/static/gen/app.js?40c12882"></script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: the Flask [config documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/) passes a string to from_object like `app.config.from_object('configmodule.ProductionConfig')` - could this be relevant? Might be worth printing out app.config to see if it's getting set properly

Comment: You can pass a object too: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Config.from_object I've watched the app.config while debugging, and it's with the correct keys. I've also tried to config directly in the app.config['KEYNAME'] without success :(

Comment: You have set your config's object to `DEBUG = False` but is *Flask's* debug mode also set to `False`?

Comment: Yep. I call app.run(host='0.0.0.0'), wich sets debug=False by default, I guess. I´ll edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Found the problem. The latest version of Flask-Assets on pip (0.10) does not contain the CDN feature described on docs for current version, that is 0.10.

Comment: how did you fix that?

Comment: I downloaded the code from master branch and put it in an "external" directory inside my project. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also put this line in your requirements.txt:
`git+git://github.com/miracle2k/flask-assets.git#flask-assets`
But he should really release a new version...